# C# unable to understand how static property works

Tags: c#, static-methods

I am a novice to C# language. I have created a user form and added a listview (chnaged it to public) on it. Now I have added a static classlike this

```
public static class listView
    {
        private static ListView.ListViewItemCollection litm;
        public static ListView.ListViewItemCollection listItems
        {

            get
            {
                Form1 frm = new Form1();
                return frm.listView1.Items;
            }

            set
            {
                litm = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Now added following code behind a button     ,

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(listView.listItems.Count.ToString()); //Works
            listView.listItems.Add("Fail"); //Fails
            this.listView1.Items.Add("HH"); //Works
        }
```

Here, I am able to use get the count of items. I think `get` works. But when I am trying to add a new item, it does nothing. No error but no entry is added.

I am interested to learn why that's happening. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: `Form1 frm = new Form1();` in your get is defiantly a problem. Instead of using static properties to let two forms talk to each other create a 3rd class that both forms share a instance of.

Comment: Do you understand that `new` creates a fresh unrelated object? The list view on that fresh form instance is also new and unrelated.

Comment: Yes, I do. :) It was just dodging me. Some times second opinions/ eyes are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your getter for property, you are creating a new instance of form 1 and add item to that.

It is not related to being static or non-static.

Look at this:

```
get
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    return frm.listView1.Items;
}
```

So when you

```
listView.listItems.Add("Fail");
```

you are adding item to list view of form 1 that you can't see it.

Infact every time you access `listView.listItems` property, you are creating a newinstance of form 1 and adding an item to its listview1.

But in this line:

```
this.listView1.Items.Add("HH");
```

you are adding the item to the list view that you are seeing.

**To learn about static:**

- [static (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

Comment: OK, now I get it where I am wrong.  Thanks!  So, is it possible to make this  static class usable some how. I mean, is it possible to do what I am trying to do? Basically, I am creating a com exposed user control for VBA. Now I need to mimic the listView Object model similar to the one in VBA. Like `ListView.ListItems.clear()`.Please let me know if its possible. I will ask another question with these details.

Comment: @cyboashu you are welcome:). It seems it is possible and there is no need to static, but in your new question, describe exactly what you need and feel free to inform me when you asked your new question:)

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489750/how-to-access-forms-controls-via-static-class